# can't clone from codecommit grc url getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'

Tags: python, git, git-clone, aws-codecommit

when I try to clone a repo (grc) from code commit I get the following error message:

```
Cloning into 'new_cdk'...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/git-remote-codecommit", line 5, in <module>
    from git_remote_codecommit import main
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/git-remote-codecommit/1.17_1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/git_remote_codecommit/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from botocore.credentials import JSONFileCache
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/git-remote-codecommit/1.17_1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/botocore/credentials.py", line 26, in <module>
    from dateutil.parser import parse
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/git-remote-codecommit/1.17_1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dateutil/parser/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from ._parser import parse, parser, parserinfo, ParserError
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/git-remote-codecommit/1.17_1/libexec/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dateutil/parser/_parser.py", line 42, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
```

even when I use .venv and install the package using pip install six, the same error occurs.

Answer (score 2):

In this case use the following command:
pip install --upgrade git-remote-codecommit

happy? like!